# View renders but doesn't update

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ive got a view that i pass a model to. I want it to render out a table out of a list in the model. It does that just fine it renders the view in that case that if i debugg it i can se the values goes to the right places. But the browser never updates. If i press ctrl+R in the browser it renders the view again in the exact same way but this time it show the list in the browser. Can i make this update everytime the view renders so that i don't have to press ctrl+R?

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateResource(ViewModel view)
    {
        view.ResourceDateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        viewmodel = view;
        Session["ViewModel"]=viewmodel;
        return View("Index", viewmodel);
    }
```

The view:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
        <th>
             MetaDataName
        </th>
        <th>
            MetaDataDescription
        </th>
        <th>
            LanguageCode
        </th>
        <th>
            UserId
        </th>
        <th>
            MetaDataDateCreated
        </th>
        @*<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MetaList)</th>*@
    </tr>
    @if (Model.Metadata.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Metadata)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.MetaDataName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.MetaDataDescription
                </td>
                <td>
                     @item.LanguageCode
                </td>
                <td>
                     @item.UserId
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.MetaDataDateCreated.ToString()
                </td>
                <td>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>

                                MetaListId
                            </th>
                               </tr>


                        @if (item.MetaList.Count != 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var list in item.MetaList)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @list.MetaListId
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            }
                        }

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }


</table>
```

Comment: The use of Ctrl-R to show the data sounds like a caching problem. Decorate your action with something like: `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0]` and try again.